# Javax Mail Session, Apache Commons Mail And Postfix Send As Spam

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, postfix-mta

Development Environment:

1. Ubuntu 14.0.4
2. Java 8 oracle
3. javax.mail | mail | 1.4.7
4. org.apache.commons | commons-email | 1.4

If I send email through `terminal` like:

> mail tahubulatbandung@gmail.com

The email is coming to **INBOX** with original (in `gmail`):

> Delivered-To: tahubulatbandung@gmail.com
>
> Received: by 10.129.51.141 with SMTP id z135csp156716ywz;
>           Thu, 9 Jun 2016 00:26:03 -0700 (PDT)
>
> X-Received: by 10.13.223.135 with SMTP id
>   i129mr4894376ywe.144.1465457163676;
>           Thu, 09 Jun 2016 00:26:03 -0700 (PDT)
>
> Return-Path:
>
> Received: from clickspayment.com ([31.220.107.128])
>           by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id h1si1253884ywc.22.2016.06.09.00.26.03
>           for 
>           (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
>           Thu, 09 Jun 2016 00:26:03 -0700 (PDT)
>
> Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning
>   root@clickspayment.com does not designate 31.220.107.128 as permitted
>   sender) client-ip=31.220.107.128;
>
> Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
>          dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@clickspayment.com;
>          spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning root@clickspayment.com does not designate 31.220.107.128 as permitted
>   sender) smtp.mailfrom=root@clickspayment.com
>
> Received: by clickspayment.com (Postfix, from userid 0)   id
>   748083C1387; Thu,  9 Jun 2016 03:26:03 -0400 (EDT)
>
> DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
>   d=clickspayment.com;  s=mail; t=1465457163;
>     bh=Ck5SoRNWUpSR4X0COv7R5ub2pUTtl6xz4dTFz++ji4M=;
>     h=To:Subject:Date:From;
>     b=mNu86iHLxiV4fCP4msTOwsf6/fX9u/6NaQZ++A6kJv/OHMPhyK0FnT3+MDH/tY6VT
>   g6WTzaTbt1DD4mF2N52Jb+5Ht/3v76U/TcpuQ7pLldrdu0z1JwAwuPd8CiZzW87WbW
>   r5zOsuvTi4NJ5DDzG5Ds+yJxVNmq7sViIkYS7XXQ=
>
> To: tahubulatbandung@gmail.com
>
> Subject: test
>
> Message-Id: <20160609072603.748083C1387@clickspayment.com>
>
> Date: Thu,  9 Jun 2016 03:26:03 -0400 (EDT)
>
> From: root@clickspayment.com (root)

And `mail.log`:

> Jun  9 03:26:03 clickspayment postfix/pickup[2178]: 748083C1387: uid=0
>   from=
>
> Jun  9 03:26:03 clickspayment postfix/cleanup[2404]: 748083C1387:
>   message-id=<20160609072603.748083C1387@clickspayment.com>
>
> Jun  9 03:26:03 clickspayment postfix/qmgr[1407]: 748083C1387:
>   from=, size=347, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Jun  9 03:26:03 clickspayment postfix/smtp[2405]: 748083C1387:
>   to=,
>   relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.176.27]:25, delay=0.21,
>   delays=0.05/0.01/0.1/0.05, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK
>   1465457163 h1si1253884ywc.22 - gsmtp)
>
> Jun  9 03:26:03 clickspayment postfix/qmgr[1407]: 748083C1387: removed

But if I send use `javax.mail.Session` and `org.apache.commons.Email`, the email is coming to **SPAM** with original email:

> Delivered-To: tahubulatbandung@gmail.com
>
> Received: by 10.129.51.141 with SMTP id z135csp156186ywz;
>           Thu, 9 Jun 2016 00:24:20 -0700 (PDT)
>
> X-Received: by 10.129.74.86 with SMTP id
>   x83mr5608016ywa.38.1465457060965;
>           Thu, 09 Jun 2016 00:24:20 -0700 (PDT)
>
> Return-Path:
>
> Received: from clickspayment.com ([31.220.107.128])
>           by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id l5si1247871ywg.127.2016.06.09.00.24.20
>           for 
>           (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
>           Thu, 09 Jun 2016 00:24:20 -0700 (PDT)
>
> Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning
>   root@clickspayment.com does not designate 31.220.107.128 as permitted
>   sender) client-ip=31.220.107.128;
>
> Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
>          dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@clickspayment.com;
>          spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning root@clickspayment.com does not designate 31.220.107.128 as permitted
>   sender) smtp.mailfrom=root@clickspayment.com
>
> Received: from clickspayment.com (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
>     by clickspayment.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 949713C1386    for
>   ; Thu,  9 Jun 2016 03:24:20 -0400 (EDT)
>
> DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
>   d=clickspayment.com;  s=mail; t=1465457060;
>     bh=qEMHl+hG2/ELzab8NTCEbnlZd7Z1lat3lNrCpGce/bk=;
>     h=Date:From:To:Subject;
>     b=CHOUvAP669p40iNUdnoKhOKbVHLi1NMYQ3AnJ1p4aNZL4pFP+dJKj1qFa4g4U5Rm9
>   V/eJPUXUy6cmnuMxn66nd1Vx6sEtT3nStYqk93XL3D0f4ru681d+hpjPjXgSnecE3z
>   aG+XWUCu8owaF3wp9Tn8BzjgXLkj22yX32p4Q8Ag=
>
> Date: Thu, 9 Jun 2016 03:24:20 -0400 (EDT)
>
> From: Clicks Payment
>
> To: Tahu Bulat Bandung
>
> Message-ID: <1482652801.13.1465457060576.JavaMail.root@clickspayment>
>
> Subject: Selamat bergabung Tahu Bulat Bandung di Clicks Payment
>
> MIME-Version: 1.0
>
> Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
>     boundary="----=_Part_12_76930216.1465457060575"
>
> ------=_Part_12_76930216.1465457060575
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
>
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

and `mail.log`:

> Jun  9 03:24:20 clickspayment postfix/smtpd[2340]: connect from
>   localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
>
> Jun  9 03:24:20 clickspayment postfix/smtpd[2340]: 949713C1386:
>   client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
>
> Jun  9 03:24:20 clickspayment postfix/cleanup[2345]: 949713C1386:
>   message-id=<1482652801.13.1465457060576.JavaMail.root@clickspayment>
>
> Jun  9 03:24:20 clickspayment postfix/qmgr[1407]: 949713C1386:
>   from=, size=1208, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Jun  9 03:24:20 clickspayment postfix/smtpd[2340]: disconnect from
>   localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
>
> Jun  9 03:24:20 clickspayment postfix/smtpd[2340]: connect from
>   localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
>
> Jun  9 03:24:20 clickspayment postfix/smtpd[2340]: A0CAE3C1387:
>   client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
>
> Jun  9 03:24:20 clickspayment postfix/cleanup[2345]: A0CAE3C1387:
>   message-id=<2025713591.15.1465457060656.JavaMail.root@clickspayment>
>
> Jun  9 03:24:20 clickspayment postfix/qmgr[1407]: A0CAE3C1387:
>   from=, size=1037, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Jun  9 03:24:20 clickspayment postfix/smtpd[2340]: disconnect from
>   localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
>
> Jun  9 03:24:20 clickspayment postfix/smtp[2346]: 949713C1386:
>   to=,
>   relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.176.27]:25, delay=0.37,
>   delays=0.05/0.01/0.07/0.24, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK
>   1465457060 l5si1247871ywg.127 - gsmtp)
>
> Jun  9 03:24:20 clickspayment postfix/qmgr[1407]: 949713C1386: removed
>
> Jun  9 03:24:22 clickspayment postfix/smtp[2347]: A0CAE3C1387:
>   to=,
>   relay=mta6.am0.yahoodns.net[98.136.216.25]:25, delay=2.1,
>   delays=0.04/0.01/0.5/1.5, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 ok dirdel)
>
> Jun  9 03:24:22 clickspayment postfix/qmgr[1407]: A0CAE3C1387: removed

All of original email:

> Delivered-To: tahubulatbandung@gmail.com
>
> Received: by 10.129.51.141 with SMTP id z135csp102207ywz;
>           Fri, 10 Jun 2016 01:00:37 -0700 (PDT)
>
> X-Received: by 10.37.193.194 with SMTP id
>   r185mr267300ybf.134.1465545637684;
>           Fri, 10 Jun 2016 01:00:37 -0700 (PDT)
>
> Return-Path:
>
> Received: from clickspayment.com ([31.220.107.128])
>           by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id i15si523000ywc.107.2016.06.10.01.00.37
>           for 
>           (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
>           Fri, 10 Jun 2016 01:00:37 -0700 (PDT)
>
> Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning
>   root@clickspayment.com does not designate 31.220.107.128 as permitted
>   sender) client-ip=31.220.107.128;
>
> Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
>          dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@clickspayment.com;
>          spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning root@clickspayment.com does not designate 31.220.107.128 as permitted
>   sender) smtp.mailfrom=root@clickspayment.com
>
> Received: from clickspayment.com (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
>     by clickspayment.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 312873C13C3    for
>   ; Fri, 10 Jun 2016 04:00:37 -0400 (EDT)
>
> DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
>   d=clickspayment.com;  s=mail; t=1465545637;
>     bh=pE0DkDEfJeuwh6Y4b12fsUQrMeqvh1RXyn3pGeU9lbY=;
>     h=Date:From:To:Subject;
>     b=qOhNNajIwDPfHKyUyVPmYtZqc7MSu3cjejpERcwUbzZa5aHRThuNGTTgcLsM7mAKE
>   TKf4KA+drC1Xkd94cZUiiMZ91bmr1Kd9bUKgOyZQTj1kvGycHiEAguJgq7jJ5vNfYT
>   HAEY7Kp4giVKDYBxnDRdcbUtnErmzPa8HtMQnsIE=
>
> Date: Fri, 10 Jun 2016 04:00:37 -0400 (EDT)
>
> From: Clicks Payment
>
> To: tahubulatbandung
>
> Message-ID: <1229938465.1.1465545637134.JavaMail.root@clickspayment>
>
> Subject: Selamat bergabung tahubulatbandung di Clicks Payment
>
> MIME-Version: 1.0
>
> Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
>     boundary="----=_Part_0_237960750.1465545637084"
>
> ------=_Part_0_237960750.1465545637084
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
>
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

`<p> Hai tahubulatbandung... <br/> Terimakasih sudah bersedia bergabung` `dengan kami di <a href="https://www.clickspayment.com/">Clicks` `Payment</a>. <br/> Kode verifikasi: <code>XXXX</code> <br/> Silahkan` `verifikasi akun Anda <a href="https://www.clickspayment.com//verify/customer/">disini</a> <br/>` `<br/> <br/> Sincerely, <br/>  Clicks Payment Team <br/>  <a href="https://www.clickspayment.com/">https://www.clickspayment.com/</a>` `</p>`

> ------=_Part_0_237960750.1465545637084--

After I added `SPF - Pass` and simple email `use mail in terimal`, I got the original email like this and it is in **SPAM** T.T:

> Delivered-To: rudi.mail90@gmail.com
>
> Received: by 10.13.209.130 with SMTP id t124csp158132ywd;
>           Fri, 10 Jun 2016 03:02:55 -0700 (PDT)
>
> X-Received: by 10.129.73.18 with SMTP id
>   w18mr557700ywa.176.1465552975076;
>           Fri, 10 Jun 2016 03:02:55 -0700 (PDT)
>
> Return-Path:
>
> Received: from clickspayment.com ([31.220.107.128])
>           by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id z82si2376857ywz.355.2016.06.10.03.02.55
>           for 
>           (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
>           Fri, 10 Jun 2016 03:02:55 -0700 (PDT)
>
> Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of root@clickspayment.com
>   designates 31.220.107.128 as permitted sender)
>   client-ip=31.220.107.128;
>
> Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
>          dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@clickspayment.com;
>          spf=pass (google.com: domain of root@clickspayment.com designates 31.220.107.128 as permitted sender)
>   smtp.mailfrom=root@clickspayment.com
>
> Received: by clickspayment.com (Postfix, from userid 0)   id
>   D65993C13C5; Fri, 10 Jun 2016 06:02:54 -0400 (EDT)
>
> DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
>   d=clickspayment.com;  s=mail; t=1465552974;
>     bh=4uXyTgHBr7HkMrUJTAkZhWiC4S4lwgKuOxnShvQDBn4=;
>     h=To:Subject:Date:From;
>     b=HLX5O5JBtLlLC8TJeq6aG1W+VQqoTJK2e6P0YAX3iTmTp7ZibxLc3TCnUPyv/66zf
>   ghtya2vvRSaxywrQR4scfXboOfjuWE6P/sFSbbD5DJjCWER0UCBr/bEDAt7RsBoIV/
>   R+y7VSeltEdAvfEbb1acobdrNhTn7zO/MdT46cFI=
>
> To: rudi.mail90@gmail.com
>
> Subject: tttttt
>
> Message-Id: <20160610100254.D65993C13C5@clickspayment.com>
>
> Date: Fri, 10 Jun 2016 06:02:54 -0400 (EDT)
>
> From: root@clickspayment.com (root)
>
> tttttttttttt

After I configured 3 points:

1. **Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of root@clickspayment.com designates 31.220.107.128 as permitted sender) client-ip=31.220.107.128;**
2. Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
      **dkim=pass header.i=@clickspayment.com;**
      spf=pass (google.com: domain of root@clickspayment.com designates 31.220.107.128 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=root@clickspayment.com
3. Received: from clickspayment.com (clickspayment.com [31.220.107.128])
   by clickspayment.com (Postfix) with ESMTPA id 48BCE3C13E4
   for ; Sat, 11 Jun 2016 22:53:36 -0400 (EDT) --> <strike>I am not sure for</strike> `localhost.localdomain`. After I tested for

   Received: from clickspayment.com (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
       by clickspayment.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 2686A3C13EB
       for ; Mon, 13 Jun 2016 01:00:07 -0400 (EDT), the email is coming to **INBOX**

**the email is coming in INBOX Gmail and the icon is not "?" anymore..**

**the email is coming in INBOX Yahoo**

BUT, other problem is appear in **HOTMAIL** T.T, the email is coming to **EMAIL JUNK**, the source:

> Received: from HK2PR0401MB1265.apcprd04.prod.outlook.com
>   (10.165.179.143) by  PS1PR0401MB1273.apcprd04.prod.outlook.com
>   (10.165.67.148) with Microsoft SMTP  Server (TLS) id 15.1.511.8 via
>   Mailbox Transport; Sun, 12 Jun 2016 10:13:19  +0000
>
> Received: from PS1PR0401CA0037.apcprd04.prod.outlook.com
>   (10.169.107.175) by  HK2PR0401MB1265.apcprd04.prod.outlook.com
>   (10.165.179.143) with Microsoft  SMTP Server (TLS) id 15.1.517.8; Sun,
>   12 Jun 2016 10:13:18 +0000
>
> Received: from HK2APC01FT115.eop-APC01.prod.protection.outlook.com 
>   (2a01:111:f400:7ebc::202) by PS1PR0401CA0037.outlook.office365.com 
>   (2a01:111:e400:7a06::47) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id
>   15.1.517.8 via  Frontend Transport; Sun, 12 Jun 2016 10:13:18 +0000
>
> Received: from COL004-MC5F18.hotmail.com (10.152.248.56) by 
>   HK2APC01FT115.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.152.248.194) with
>   Microsoft  SMTP Server (TLS) id 15.1.497.8 via Frontend Transport;
>   Sun, 12 Jun 2016  10:13:16 +0000
>
> Received: from clickspayment.com ([31.220.107.128]) by
>   COL004-MC5F18.hotmail.com over TLS secured channel with Microsoft
>   SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.23143);   Sun, 12 Jun 2016 03:13:12 -0700
>
> Received: from clickspayment.com (clickspayment.com [31.220.107.128])
>     by clickspayment.com (Postfix) with ESMTPA id 277F73C13E5   for
>   ; Sun, 12 Jun 2016 06:13:12 -0400 (EDT)
>
> DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
>   d=clickspayment.com;  s=mail; t=1465726392;
>     bh=6R+sDK3a+Nm8ONd5nWdnHqQr8rLcG6RddSd7HT79G60=;
>     h=Date:From:To:Subject;
>     b=uGDPjM7v4HgkQ4NDpnOc2Z9u8mh4snZ9lHkaAOxupFE9mLNn2C6bsOLwvcTQnyVXs
>   g8pXZFVKxwGZrOciPGOVQTU5EtpecoFqTHiaVhp4K5QxrKSPM3qL+UHN5wgSu0YaAj
>   5jVDcfSEd/tXOton8m8bJbE/cTdyY2+gnDok+4pA=
>
> Date: Sun, 12 Jun 2016 06:13:12 -0400 (EDT)
>
> From: Clicks Payment
>
> To: tahubulatbandung hotmail
>
> Message-ID: <463059015.69.1465726392129.JavaMail.root@clickspayment>
>
> Subject: Selamat bergabung tahubulatbandung hotmail di Clicks Payment
>
> Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
>     boundary="----=_Part_68_1847825176.1465726392129"
>
> Return-Path: root@clickspayment.com
>
> X-OriginalArrivalTime: 12 Jun 2016 10:13:13.0077 (UTC)
>   FILETIME=[07378250:01D1C493]
>   X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id:
>   c902588a-7a30-4663-0f04-08d392aa2cd7 X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
>   X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa:0
>   X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming
>   CMM-sender-ip: 31.220.107.128 CMM-sending-ip: 31.220.107.128
>   CMM-Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is
>    31.220.107.128) smtp.mailfrom=root@clickspayment.com; dkim=pass  header.d=clickspayment.com; x-hmca=pass
>   header.id=root@clickspayment.com CMM-X-SID-PRA: root@clickspayment.com
>   CMM-X-AUTH-Result: PASS CMM-X-SID-Result: PASS CMM-X-Message-Status:
>   n:n CMM-X-Message-Delivery:
>   Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD02 CMM-X-Message-Info:
>   11chDOWqoTkt3yvh78JX2/1GLc6Fn3NhXIWFocXMiMxzKaT3WCIdutXxwVo9JvxThCDxpMlwmlBfQQ6fyD2zO6Q/qoM4Brk5AKq/qbyQyjU+FTJHPg4zzulpGSnv8MTt/Ckr0nTUcjgR22MTdoZAt5OVoNdGb/o2K72ORVABSu9K5BNHn5POGBCQlNTVXIaMi08hNzUizuIEioM75BKLogwin2khuRYQTrO6wG+PMfs=
>   X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 6 X-MS-Exchange-Organization-PCL: 2
>   X-Forefront-Antispam-Report:
>   EFV:NLI;SFV:SKS;SFS:;DIR:INB;SFP:;SCL:6;SRVR:HK2PR0401MB1265;H:COL004-MC5F18.hotmail.com;FPR:;SPF:None;CAT:NONE;LANG:id;CAT:NONE;
>   X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id:
>   c902588a-7a30-4663-0f04-08d392aa2cd7 X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
>   1;HK2PR0401MB1265;2:7I7yhjxXht1wu1qHrQ54lg3zC9MfA6WlBt9n4Ey7ruKirtxHmgwCMK3pqbaRGab2EkkUSPpku37GSSXN+5OBhDpbPsq1dFC/JVmuUWTFUmu2sKwadsNTJ0jYbMTarQAArzAoowZisDh4oarV8JCwsC9VpzM+jLrUKVFO0O3wPu5lmQyySEPBOT2+1KGizlvVuVCAxKqWR87f+QztrN85ug==;3:MbzZZnvwFDlEu7s8Win/LVW0BEtQRiajY3grrnu/4RctNiZIPfe0Ry+BpLRyY7bAHlZ4APLy/VWPEiourQrZTjO4LdcMQoS4RIWYWbrNdYUTm+B5FeFTVu5DvgebKmBTBUt7SP6PnKIvj79C76i0UIEWyVHvQDg3mJ5VD1a+meo=;25:erDwLW1PetkpjL9QCFN8BYvlD66iZ3MH7PpwBpCssUOx3l9NlcPNMkbvtq8654/Pm02zAO1NEKy7w7O5nFFlYURrngRn1+bX9R3o+8ythJZcd8AwLYLCS4z91Fi11shxW0qR6o7Rd9igHkNyyq8oEC1GuqBepc0cnplOT+EdncFJ6tJGzKFHQuTJDBGQxSm9AJdkzBV2KrvD9YRptP9IP2JxVkS9FBgchSHLWXXA4gPT1ykzZaE3o5jVapKwDeUzTWQCAdYE8+t0QWE6b9/PYGMorDp2eM44RtLGWAL7oTjKHc2iGFdC+TEwO8uOnMO9f0Na93smSLTfmKM3FcLL5JOSLsnjIaA+Tp+AA00l0iTX2IbxPawNz/eIjCZpIoEnsn13QZQaWY0xFComF/229aA0LV+E+g4Lr71/0Tl7oKS0vA2a0SqO3PBHhACCgeaD
>   X-Microsoft-Antispam:
>   BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(8291501002);SRVR:HK2PR0401MB1265;
>   X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-CFA-Test:
>   BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(82015046);SRVR:HK2PR0401MB1265;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:;SRVR:HK2PR0401MB1265;
>   X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
>     1;HK2PR0401MB1265;4:YUp/5V1dNFwU4G7NhRsxCbI1Jjd+T9zOggeQ1fUwgThfDpH+F8bb4TcqYrqvbNKor6oE8KM5vL7+PsBSmbuEqG8bbC2Kexuu1o9veHRWwPii03vIYsnP3C5TXPRDcfD7kpdJA9+oWn2NVFsZx6CuYxZqHp8EqN++W0YfmfIqdt07h573bpT90txoSgVmlJ7Noxcumubl6wefCeCWqeDM5SkEMEoH7Tiq0zn8c6ChbveAZ3nk3s75jBh8jViK9CZMzJ8SI6JqWjxVcXtDiGRmuQ==;23:3ZXOE18TQxop8c4cR27I3YlhVAI55M3yqOx+qia0MAMsY9K96MAgy7hp5x0yi54mss/KkhgBVTGvTyHk+KSfnrjYsINn4PTfSPll56FvEyu/QbwowdFuXrKgrOcnptm/8E65gKwDaf5d1r/Spcw3T/aVBAtvF5q9ZJrHVsNRixujYg90+LW/9ccNwgjAmppV;6:aPDIYHsB5feRz/WdGJXQzwTQwZXWTe00L3FmigNAJrnFY8HJmi21T+ACydl/c1QKt/CdLQ0UhhAdPJisvboNzZ2o9dIjq5+IiP+0UV6UQ0+jv18ipM2EwkEpEgjht3U7kaqUCe7eIC3NTrmAfs67LzrCZSwYHscDMw6voFk93Nrhup2K6m4W6KSEpnk+ZSPoyNCFzDumcILy+IFi1IGYpf40E/FOfibzGTb9C0MQhxzRE3kXI5g/RLgOG6xRv6JMORTLODBKEZHeVDqY9RvPRM3u3r88ZtrphiS15+Z8g00ea9qcWQNTRD10jcZ0yviq;5:cy68nKmmKv0DaYm2GtRcQ301vS80x3l1b6br6shxYmNhpJRRpMUe4jGOmtRTIANdS3ju9eBQn9xtLn2p7u1DjrXhpn8kLonjEd3l865nh90uDGVczR/ebXS8IxyN4lHB9pCdehyCwGgp8EHzIW3hig==
>   X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
>   1;HK2PR0401MB1265;24:znstvMAJiStGTnUgjFS5tLXl7HLe3l1orbdiC4GetY+hojWKOGkvjkEdN/flhwiQ4ChXD2tq3z8hevS6/mSXsw==;7:pqHnUd1NiIYouQWHdczgOeHzujkEV5zduKi3tzRIArgXsLCbBDi1nrQwVHw9aHv+013FpzRjBEs0Er9ilovIyjK8I8RBpMSoBkwG1jM9taMYYZGlpOVKfP0pDfZEGNsoV89crb2b2RTybp/cEn1JpAvgjqxgp8wjATYoN93YTp3+O46mYdxpVCbB9nOAk/QzKj/+T6iYaWtYr6sbAtxCv0LYHbN0sh2Wvb1a2rjON3Q=
>   SpamDiagnosticOutput: 1:99 SpamDiagnosticMetadata: SKS
>   X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 12 Jun 2016
>   10:13:16.7471  (UTC) X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id:
>   84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa
>   X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
>   X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: HK2PR0401MB1265
>   X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource:
>   HK2APC01FT115.eop-APC01.prod.protection.outlook.com
>   X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
>   X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:03.0905767
>   X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
>     =?us-ascii?Q?1;PS1PR0401MB1273;9:xXteLEoBRMm+UFOM9d+jTbeSlMZSaKXGFK85eyeI?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?dsdk+Rkx1XaRHyLpD3fKliOPuUvZECMmEqBsP8IBk7gLhfztSt67ygmcHJ7W?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?VCckSpoyPVuPb/L1Kf8vFMT/c5JtFfeAUGSUBr7DWZEw7BIYrQizr3yflHQx?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?ayqDdai3Yft5+lTKkmsosardhmBbCWXct19V08GWY1o288MYA9Iz/cLs5mmY?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?/SrjvcktD1HdCOb+bQOztlGM67ycKbkHBCBrQGX5xTWeD7vo5oSPn0u9YPgm?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?vGxOvmj2Au5RxLH+voGyXZGiT8EqBx/nwZBW+EyxfNLinqP4GBdVX/fLOo4u?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?2EOBY6rxTkVsaVmwcoboRT8jtpsDTBt3mTt+4llAzu+3VzG4V7PVDiIN18fL?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?LbX+SWPcwCnX67cpZUNJ15ikVLwFWiRa1bt13yp5DEcf3PyFtlZ1LVdtGnPp?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?GOYpt7IOomLnSi8vJyknL5VHuFEp9rNl5idAFiPENj6cmQn5qMTqtjfKjoZf?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?B+mNpXkYdqAZMFvYbAwtaQBDRB5Q80SoBHWYUvri0peT0hlu0ZVL/FkV3GHo?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?fpuP2LAmZvOEpaZgkUcJHeWWxhd21oND+dYGfoV2l5g6/q0dT+94/TodNpmL?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?y5SnrWHmbR7/KQvuPUfUS3jbaewk+Y2e1h2//X2wfqSxjcNALAqoelNjrG1A?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?4K7SPFoC9xTc1D+/1cQ4uFrKkbhkLmzMu2ZDhbPkEQaT5dGFU02GBZTOne47?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?9q9EF8ftW8ct+f5TFE2l+mds7l+4wqz8yCxCOxyz8bvMKpqfJUm2MMxfjKn0?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?IiSVd/9Xp3xBs4TXspxlZBBmzUH2ZI8rKLOWNMXR/BA56G4zYB8ztggSxB5q?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?3sIcJvsFupc1i2bnR3eSjjROYCMJAOhoqFqG3QQHxKxka9YYhitHogkUNOLB?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?hY5I4jBlaZNFxHV9cOqfWn9hrTo/pf3106J8Xs2nRMmN2a4L+xxbt+NZJLoa?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?f//CvK1lfFvytjptaVgegzwcZyYd67NIZpF1UBEff+C5+F/nxsJsn//bt4eq?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?gFqEguQQkadWoHPNNEJBPN66wKtA?= X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
>     abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;ijl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:J;WIMS-SenderIP:31.220.107.128;WIMS-SPF:clickspayment%2ec;WIMS-DKIM:clickspayment%2ec;WIMS-822:root%40clickspayment%2ecom;WIMS-PRA:root%40clickspayment%2ecom;WIMS-AUTH:PASS;ENG:(102400050)(102420017);RF:JunkEmail;OFR:SpamFilterAuthJ;
>   MIME-Version: 1.0
>
> ------=_Part_68_1847825176.1465726392129 Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii" Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>   X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
>     =?us-ascii?Q?1;PS1PR0401MB1273;9:xXteLEoBRMm+UFOM9d+jTbeSlMZSaKXGFK85eyeI?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?dsdk+Rkx1XaRHyLpD3fKliOPuUvZECMmEqBsP8IBk7gLhfztSt67ygmcHJ7W?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?VCckSpoyPVuPb/L1Kf8vFMT/c5JtFfeAUGSUBr7DWZEw7BIYrQizr3yflHQx?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?ayqDdai3Yft5+lTKkmsosardhmBbCWXct19V08GWY1o288MYA9Iz/cLs5mmY?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?/SrjvcktD1HdCOb+bQOztlGM67ycKbkHBCBrQGX5xTWeD7vo5oSPn0u9YPgm?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?vGxOvmj2Au5RxLH+voGyXZGiT8EqBx/nwZBW+EyxfNLinqP4GBdVX/fLOo4u?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?2EOBY6rxTkVsaVmwcoboRT8jtpsDTBt3mTt+4llAzu+3VzG4V7PVDiIN18fL?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?LbX+SWPcwCnX67cpZUNJ15ikVLwFWiRa1bt13yp5DEcf3PyFtlZ1LVdtGnPp?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?GOYpt7IOomLnSi8vJyknL5VHuFEp9rNl5idAFiPENj6cmQn5qMTqtjfKjoZf?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?B+mNpXkYdqAZMFvYbAwtaQBDRB5Q80SoBHWYUvri0peT0hlu0ZVL/FkV3GHo?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?fpuP2LAmZvOEpaZgkUcJHeWWxhd21oND+dYGfoV2l5g6/q0dT+94/TodNpmL?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?y5SnrWHmbR7/KQvuPUfUS3jbaewk+Y2e1h2//X2wfqSxjcNALAqoelNjrG1A?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?4K7SPFoC9xTc1D+/1cQ4uFrKkbhkLmzMu2ZDhbPkEQaT5dGFU02GBZTOne47?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?9q9EF8ftW8ct+f5TFE2l+mds7l+4wqz8yCxCOxyz8bvMKpqfJUm2MMxfjKn0?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?IiSVd/9Xp3xBs4TXspxlZBBmzUH2ZI8rKLOWNMXR/BA56G4zYB8ztggSxB5q?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?3sIcJvsFupc1i2bnR3eSjjROYCMJAOhoqFqG3QQHxKxka9YYhitHogkUNOLB?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?hY5I4jBlaZNFxHV9cOqfWn9hrTo/pf3106J8Xs2nRMmN2a4L+xxbt+NZJLoa?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?f//CvK1lfFvytjptaVgegzwcZyYd67NIZpF1UBEff+C5+F/nxsJsn//bt4eq?=
>   =?us-ascii?Q?gFqEguQQkadWoHPNNEJBPN66wKtA?= X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
>     abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;ijl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:J;WIMS-SenderIP:31.220.107.128;WIMS-SPF:clickspayment%2ec;WIMS-DKIM:clickspayment%2ec;WIMS-822:root%40clickspayment%2ecom;WIMS-PRA:root%40clickspayment%2ecom;WIMS-AUTH:PASS;ENG:(102400050)(102420017);RF:JunkEmail;OFR:SpamFilterAuthJ;

and I am going to dig what is going on in HOTMAIL.

For error Hotmail, move on http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-ocompose/spf-and-dkim-are-pass-but-the-email-come-to-junk/237c0d2b-350c-4a7f-9b7a-dbda8cc5af88

Comment: This is about the content of your email, not computer programming. Off topic.

Comment: Hai @EJP thanks for you care.. The problem in gmail is done like above -"After I configured 3 point:"

Answer (score 1):

When you use the "mail" command, it's sending a simple plain text email message.  The message you're sending with Apache Commons Email (JavaMail) is a more complex multipart message with an embedded html body.  Spam filters use a variety of rules to guess at what's spam and what's not spam.  No doubt something about the more complex message and/or the html content caused it to think your message was spam.  The usual advice here is to make sure the full content of your message really doesn't look anything like spam (assuming it really **isn't** spam).  Make sure all the addresses are legitimate.  Make sure all the URLs point to non-spam sites.  And so on.

Comment: Still come to **SPAM**, I have check the content

Comment: The content full original email is already I added above "All of original email"

Comment: No one is going to tell you the exact rules that the gmail spam filter uses to decide if your message is spam.  All you can do is vary the content of your message until gmail no longer thinks it's spam.  Try sending to a different recipient. Try sending only plain text email.  Try removing the URLs from the message.  Look at the Authentication-Results header and fix any of the problems it points out.  Experiment until you determine what aspects of the message are causing gmail to mark it as spam.

Comment: 1.Received: from clickspayment.com (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]) by clickspayment.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 312873C13C3 for ; Fri, 10 Jun 2016 04:00:37 -0400 (EDT);
2.Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of root@clickspayment.com designates 31.220.107.128 as permitted sender) client-ip=31.220.107.128;; 
3.Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@clickspayment.com;spf=pass (google.com: domain of root@clickspayment.com designates 31.220.107.128 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=root@clickspayment.com.
How about 3 points, some missed?

Comment: Looks like you fixed most of those errors.  If it's still failing, I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Did you try all the other things I suggested?

Comment: I did @Bill Shannon in above "After I added SPF - Pass and simple email use mail in terimal, I got the original email like this and it is in SPAM T.T:"

Comment: the email is coming to inbox gmail -"After I configured 3 point:"

Answer (score 0):

It is done :) by fixing missed SPF + DKIM